# how to change cursor image during the drag in javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cursor

i have a problem

i can't change size of cursor image

what's wrong with my code?

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e){
    var img = new Image(30, 40);
    img.src = "http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/d18eea9d28f3490b8dcbfa9e38f8336e.jpg";
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, -15, -15);
},false);
```

i put my code on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CNuk9/

Comment: What browser are you testing this on?

Comment: i'm testing this on google chrome browser

Comment: Does the drag & drop work? can you post a fiddle of your code?
I know that there are issues with `dataTransfer` on some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
.triggerHandler("dragstart", function(e)....
```

This worked for me once to solve an issue i had once similar  your first problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cursor by changing the CSS properties, check [this link](http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm) for list of css properties for different cursors

Hope that helps!

Comment: it does'nt help me.i want to change image below (or other sides) of cursor during the drag